Existence of a nice partition for any graph
Let $G$ be any finite graph. Can we always find a partition $(X,Y)$ of the set of vertices $V$, that is $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $X \cup Y = V$, satisfying:
$|\{v \in Y ~:~ v\sim x\}| \geq |\{v \in X ~:~ v\sim x\}|, \quad \forall x \in X$,
and
$|\{v \in X ~:~ v\sim y\}| \geq |\{v \in Y ~:~ v\sim y\}|, \quad \forall y \in Y$?

Context please...

This is always possible in a maximum cut.
Let $(X,Y)$ be a maximum cut of $G$, i.e., a bipartition of vertices of $G$ such that the number of edges from $X$ to $Y$ is as large as possible. Say a vertex $v$ in $X$ has strictly more neighbours in $X$ than in $Y$. Then, moving the vertex $v$ from $X$ to $Y$ gives strictly more edges across the cut, which is a contradiction.

Nice answer! Thanks.
